# how to parse floating hexadecimal string in java

Tags: java, type-conversion

my hexadecimal string
`string s=new String("FF7900002481201132570943440402151302961500080054021E000040FFFFFBFF79000024812011");`

i want particular data in string..
my format : 2481201132570943440402151302961500080054021E000040FFFFFBFF790000

it's must starting value in string 24 .
and it's split at end of 62 . values(2481201132570943440402151302961500080054021E000040FFFFFBFF790000=62)
and finally to split the string ?

---

### 12 content value in hexadecimal

24 ---> (1)
8120113257 --(5)
094047   ---(3)
040215    ---(3)
13029615  -----  (4)
00         ------- (1)
080054021E -------(5)
000040  ----  (3)
FFFFFBFF  -- (4)
79          ---(1)
00      ------(1)
00       -----  (1)

how to solve it in java code?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like your homework with bad task formulation.

Comment: Please add context and make the question more clear. What have you tried ? Please add your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the String as a series of Strings.

```
class StringParser {
     final StringReader sr;
     public StringParser(String text) {
          sr = new StringReader(text);
     }

     public String next(int n) {
          char[] chars = new char[n];
          sr.read(chars);
          return new String(chars);
     }

     public String nextAsLong(int n) {
          return Long.parseInt(next(n));
     }
}

StringParser sp = new StringParser("FF7900002481201132570943440402151302961500080054021E000040FFFFFBFF79000024812011");
sp.next(8); // ignored
long first= sp.nextAsLong(2);
long second = sp.nextLong(10);
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`Long.parseLong(string, 16);`

Answer (score 0):

Size of content is fixed or floating?
If yes you can use substring and: Long.parseLong("FFFFFBFF", 16);

Comment: its a floating content ,, @shamil